# Warming up soup in crockpot

Tags: food-safety

I have to take a soup to a party but my kids only like the Pacific brand of tomato soup. I am wondering if it's safe to put in the crock pot to heat up and take it with me. Thanks,
Kay

Comment: Hello Kay, I am somewhat confused by your question, since I see multiple possible interpretations. Do you mean that you will take the refrigerated soup and the crockpot along and heat it there? Or that you will heat first, then take everything with you, still hot? Or do you have a way to keep it plugged in while driving there? In any case, see the linked question. The important part for safety is that you prove that the internal temperature was not between 4 and 60 Celsius for more than 4 hours. Nobody here can predict if that will be the case or not in your situation, you have to measure.

Comment: @rumtscho : it's not being left out at room temp.  It's being left in a heated vessel.  If you're going to make a generic question for reheating things too slowly, fine, but this isn't the same as the general concept of that question you like to link everything to.  If anything, it's closer to https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12219/67

Comment: @Joe maybe this comes from the strange question. I understood that the OP wants to make it in the crockpot, plug it off while still hot, then transport for unknown time, then eat. If this is the plan, then the necessary concept is that once it cools down below 60 C, it is considered "room temperature", which is described in the linked question. Or do you think the OP plans something else?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes - the crockpot will heat it sufficiently.

You might find it easier to transport in a sealed container and just use the crockpot to heat/maintain temperature at the party.

However, the time taken for a crockpot to heat up is substantial compared to using a stove-top pan or even a microwave. Crockpots are really designed to slow cook foods, and maintain temperatures for keeping foods warm.